# Same primary keys error when attempting to update Db

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My app is a movie collection manager. I created an EF model-first db. I've got a `Person` entity with a `Pictures` property which is a collection of `Picture` entity.

Given a movie title, I grab all information from the web and get a list of actors `(= Person entities)`. For each of them, I create a new `List<Picture>` with a new `Picture` object that contains the picture grabbed from web.

For each `Person`, the only picture that's in the `Pictures` property has the same Id property (since they're all independent `List<Picture>`). So when I try to update database, a `DbUpdateException` is thrown saying

> Multiple added entities may have the same primary key

Easily understandable, but I always thought EF would handle all this stuff by its own (that is putting each `Picture` from each `Person.Pictures` collection in the `Picture` table would give it a different Id).

That's not the case apparently. To handle this, I'd have to create directly a `Picture` In the `Picture` table, which then has no sense for me, according to my model: a picture is attached to a person so I create it when I create a `Person` object. If not, what's the benefit to use model-first way ?

Have I missed something to handle that ?

PS: see [here](http://imageshack.com/a/img911/5909/AdmAFJ.jpg) a picture of my simplified model to illustrate how all the stuff is interconnected.

To be clearer, here's how the process runs (I left aside the code that's responsible for parsing html code to get infos from the web page ; `multipleItems` contains a set of html div that are parsed):

```
foreach (var act in multipleItems)
{
     Person myact = new Person();
     List<Picture> mylistpics = new List<Picture>();
     Picture mypic = new Picture();
     mypic.Data = /*[...code for creating image from web data...]*/
     mylistpics.Add(mypic);
     myact.Pictures = mylistpics;
     //[...]code for grabbing name of actor in webpage[...]
     myact.FirstName = names[0];
     myact.Name = names[1];
     mypersons.Add(myact);
}

mymovie.Actors = mypersons;
```

So you can see, and that's the important point, that I add the picture in the `Person`'s `Pictures` property. So each `Person` has its own independent collection of pictures: it's normal then that, for every `Person`'s collection, the picture added has an Id of 0.

When the loop's ended, I affect the `mypersons` list to Actors property of the current DataContext of my window (movie object).

Then, it's on the `Dbcontext.SaveChanges();` call (that saves the entire `Movie` object to database) that the exception is thrown.

Go [here](http://imageshack.com/a/img538/12/yIwtzQ.jpg) to see the property pane for Picture-Person Association.

Comment: I suspect foreign keys problem here. What is the complete exception message?

Comment: Here's the complete message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: Unable to determine the principal end of the 'CollectioModel.PersonPicture' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your database does not have the picture Id as an identity field, so without you setting the Id, the default value, probably 0, is causing all the same primary keys. Once you add the IDENTITY to the database table and update the EF model, you should notice that column have the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property of the Id field set to `identity` so that it is configured to work with the generated primary keys from the identity insert.

Comment: The **Id** property **is** already a **primary key**: `Entity Key` set to **True** and `StoredGeneratedPattern` set to `Identity`.

Comment: Can you post the sample code that is generating the error then?

Comment: But do the *database columns* have identity specification?

Comment: @Arnold Since EF generated the database itself (model-first way) from my model, I presume Identities are well set...

Comment: Here's the table definition: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pictures] (
    [Id]       BIGINT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Data]     VARBINARY (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [IsMain]   BIT             NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] BIGINT          NOT NULL,
    [MediaId]  BIGINT          NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Pictures] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PersonPicture] FOREIGN KEY ([PersonId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Persons] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MediaPicture] FOREIGN KEY ([MediaId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Medias] ([Id])
);

Answer (score 0):

You make it difficult for EF to follow entities relationships with your code. Try this, this is more readable for both humans and EF:

```
Person myact = new Person
        {
          FirstName = names[0],
          Name = name[1],
          Pictures = new List<Picture>
                     {
                       new Picture { Data = previouslyComputedData }
                     }
        }
```

Additionally (or alternatively), you could also explicitly specify different Ids for `Picture` objects (negative to make sure nothing interferes). EF will overwrite them on `SaveChanges`:

```
int picId = -1;
...
          new Picture { Id = picId--, Data = previouslyComputedData }
```

**UPDATE**: Maybe EF doesn't like adding those actors all in a roll. Try saving changes after each `Person` creation:

```
Person myact = new Person { ... }
mymovie.Actors.Add(myact);
// SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Before trying your code, I ended up in the output window with: "Actor X Y ; PictureId = 0  /  Actor W Z ; PictureId = 0..etc"  Now with your code, every Id is different (negative values) but same issue...

Comment: Hmmm, weird... Did you try without specifying ids (first snippet alone)? Sorry, I won't be there today.

Comment: Becomes more and more weird... I made changes to get only **ONE** actor in `mymovie.Actors` and... same issue !

Comment: I added a link in my OP to see the Association Picture-Person property pane, if it can help...

Comment: I've just ommitted 1 thing: there's another picture, directly bounded to Movie Entity, that's added at the same time. I've just disabled this latest one, and it worked. So how can handle this ? (the Movie's picture has an Id of 0)

Comment: I've just set the Movies' Picture to arbitrary value of -327 and it works fine !! Problem solved. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @jackgames Ah, of course, there was another player! OK, glad you solved it.

Comment: Sorry for that. It's totally got out of my head. Shame on me !

Comment: I'm back with bad news: when I try to add a 2nd movie => same issue again !!? It starts driving me nuts !!!